# Setting different search order for several categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been using this:

```
 <?php 
 if (is_category(15)) {
      $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=date&order=des&cat=15'); 
   }

 else {
 if (is_category()) { 
      $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc&cat=-15'); 
   } 
 }
 ?>
```

Now I'd like to add cat 85 to be des like cat 15.

I've added

```
elseif (is_category(85)) {
  $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=date&order=des&cat=85'); 
  }
```

which seems to work, but I'm concerned about `cat=-15` in the `else` part - do I need to somehow add 85 there, and if so, how? `cat=-15,-85` or something?

**More info:** This is from archive.php in my WP blog. As I said, the above works, but it appears that the `else` repeats the original cat, 15, for some reason (`cat=-15`) so it seems like now that I've added a new cat in `elseif` that the `else` code also needs to mention 85. I tried changing `cat=-15` to `cat=-15,85` and it messed up the site.

Comment: depend how are builded your query.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know PHP at all, can you be more specific?

Comment: can you share is_category() method and what is the $query_string variable and quert_posts method

Comment: Give more details of your issue for receive sufficient help. This code is not your's ? more explaination needed. query_posts is the code of wordpress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make your query work with multiple value:

In conditions:

clause uri must finish with

```
&cat[]=-15&cat[]=-85
```

In query builder:

```
WHERE cat IN(-15,-85)
```

Something like this
(Sry on my phone. Cant code)

Comment: OK, I got it: I needed to change <code>cat=-15</code> to <code>cat=-15,-85</code>. Thanks!

Comment: your welcome :)
(be sure this change doesn't be considered as a range between -15 and -85, but really -15 "and" -85). i never used wordpress...